# CUDA driver too old for Matlab GPU?

Tags: matlab, cuda, gpu, tesla

Ok,this is something am having problems with. I recently installed Matlab R2013a on a x86_64 Linux system running RHEL 5, attached to a Tesla S2050. I have never used the GPU functionality in Matlab itself (but have tried some of it using Jacket that lets one 
program GPUs in Matlab).

The Tesla is working fine with all the drivers ,CUDA installed (Jacket v1.8.2 is running fine without complaints).

**  Driver Version: 270.41.34 (the last version from 2011, supporting S2050)  ** 
CUDA: v5.0.35
nvcc -V : Cuda compilation tools, release 5.0, V0.2.1221

But the Matlab r2013a complains:

gpuDevice errors: 
Caused by:
    The CUDA driver was found, but it is too old. The CUDA driver on your system supports CUDA version 4. The required CUDA version is 5 or greater.

Now, I understand the error that Matlab has problems with the Driver version. But, I have installed the latest CUDA toolkit and the latest driver that nVidia has to offer for the Tesla S2050 that I have.

Is there a later driver version available for this Tesla (i downloaded the latest driver & when trying to install, it simply complains that I don't have the compatible nVidia hardware).

How do I tell Matlab to consider the relevant CUDA ? (where to set PATH, CUDA_PATH etc., if any ? )
Are there any other checks i need to perform the evaluate the working of the attached Tesla ?

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use CUDA 5.0 with driver 270.41.34.  CUDA 5 requires 304.54 or newer.  This is not a MATLAB issue.

Newer drivers that support CUDA 5 will also support Tesla S2050.

For example this recent [319.17 driver](http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-amd64-319.17-driver.html) lists Tesla S2050 on the supported products tab.  Or use the 304.54 that comes with cuda 5.0.